# Unable to fetch data from nsurl

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurl

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"My URL : %@",url);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"New Data : %@",data);

UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

cell.imageView.image = tmpImage;
```

Comment: what did nslog print when you call the method?

Comment: It prints null fof NEW DATA : Null but url nslog is getting data???

Comment: can you upload your url for me to test it?

Comment: Yes Ofcourse... http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/de/e9/f6/dee9f62b-790d-1fc9-abf5-803380609ec9/mzl.wwfbjvfq.png/53x53bb-85.png

Comment: Are you entering that url without `http://` or `https://` are prefex? you need `http://`

Comment: when you get the url ,first encoder it with nsutf8stringencoding, then use the encoded url to get the nsdata, see what you can get

Comment: when you comment something contain 'http://',the stackoverflow will pass it to display...

Comment: Yes.. Indeed I did it with http://

Comment: Could u provide me the encoder code for nsutf8stringencoding such that i can implement it !!! :)'

Comment: after encoded the url, what you get now?

Comment: NSString *realUrl = [yoururl encoding:nsutf8stringencoding]; then use the realurl to get nsdata

Comment: its not working my friend

Comment: Just use this to add `http://` NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

Comment: sorry, i was wrong about the encoding code, my bad, i test your url ,and it works fine. i think maybe there is some other problem.

Comment: I wonder what did was your real problem, the ATS or the url?

Comment: his url is current, the problem is the ATS not set.

Comment: Based on the number of comments asking for clarification, it's clear you need to provide more detail and context for users to help you in this case. Please edit your question to provide a complete picture of what you're trying to accomplish, what isn't working, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will . Thank you Mate for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

i think i got your problem, check this like my upload image in your project.

i also make a gif about how to add this setting in your project , just follow the step in my gif.

[image]